# Issue regarding Initialization Lists C++

Tags: c++

For example, say I have the following code;

```
class Foo
{
    public:
    Foo(int x) : _foo(x)
    {

    }

    private:
    int _foo;

    protected:
    std::string _bar;
};

class Bar : public Foo
{
    public:
    Bar() : Foo(10), _temp("something"), _bar("something_else")
    { 

    }
    private:
    std::string _temp;
};

int main()
{
    Bar stool;
}
```

The code doesn't run because _bar is of the class Foo and it doesn't appear to know it exists, so is this not how you would go about doing it? Or would you just have _bar in Foo's constructor? This would work but what if _bar doesn't always have to be assigned something?

Edit: Below is the real code I was using;

```
Entity::Entity(GameState *state, bool collidable) 
    :_isLoaded(false), _state(state), alive(true), collidable(collidable),               name(entityDetault)
```

{

}

```
Entity::Entity(GameState *state, bool collidable, entityName _name)
    :_isLoaded(false), _state(state), alive(true), collidable(collidable), name(_name)
{

}
```

and then the child class would use this constructor;

```
Player::Player(GameState *state) 
: Entity(state,true,entityName::entityPlayer), health(100),bulletSpeed(600),_colour(sf::Color(128,255,86,255))
```

Does this all look correct now? Slightly better than doing it all in the constructor body.

Comment: In this case you why not simply assign `bar` in the constructor body rather than initialize it?

Comment: I was told it was a better programming practice to assign variables in the initalizer list instead of doing in it's body, is this not correct? Or should I only use init lists when they're for the direct members of the class?

Comment: You don't *assign* variables in initializer lists, you *initialize them*, meaning you use the constructor rather than assignment operator. This is the key difference. In such a trivial code snippet, assignment should be fine, but in actual code the answer will be different.

Answer (score 5):

The member initialiser list in a constructor of class `C` can only initialise:

- direct base classes of `C`
- direct members of `C`
- virtual base classes of `C` *(doesn't come up too often)*

The only way to initalise a member of a base class is through a constructor of the base class. Or just forego initialisation and then do an assignment in the body of `C`'s constructor. The latter cannot be used for `const` members or references, though, and in general does not do the same thing as just initialisation.

Comment: const members or reference members are questionable at best anyway :)

Comment: In your opinion what would be the best method for this? I was told that initialising members in a classes constructor was not the best method and initialiser list's should be used instead? So if this is the case should I just make another constructor for class foo with a second parameter?

Comment: @user1725794 If `Foo` is under your control, then giving it an appropriate constructor is the correct thing to do. A class's constructor should initialise all of its members in an appropriate way. And since `_bar` is protected, it's reasonable derived classes might want to initialise it as they see fit. For this, `Foo` needs the appropriate constructor.

Comment: @user1725794 Yes, member initialiser lists are the preferred way of initialising class members. Actually, they are the *only* way. Assigning values in the constructor body is an assignment, not an initialisation. Such a member will be default-initialised (due to not appearing in a member initialiser list), and then assigned to in the constructor body.

Answer (score 2):

You could either move it from the initializer list to the body (if it is not const):

```
Bar() : Foo(10), _temp("something")
{
    _bar = "something_else";
}
```

or provide a second (maybe protected) contructor for `Foo`:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(int x) : _foo(x)
    {

    }

protected:
    Foo(int x,std::string s) : _foo(x), _bar(s)
    {
    }

private:
    int _foo;

protected:
    std::string _bar;
};

class Bar : public Foo
{
public:
    Bar() : Foo(10,"something_else"), _temp("something")
    { 

    }

private:
    std::string _temp;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize the base class before you can access it. If you want to initialize member variable in the base class, you have to do it via call to base class constructor in which will initialize it's members.

Answer (score 1):

You may put `_bar` in `Foo`'s constructor's initialization list. If `_bar` does not always need be to assigned something, you can use default value.

```
class Foo
{
public:
   Foo(int x):_foo(x)
   {
   }
protected:
   Foo(int x, string s) : _foo(x),_bar(s)
   {

   }

private:
   int _foo;

protected:
   std::string _bar;
};

class Bar : public Foo
{
public:
   Bar() : Foo(10,"something else"), _temp("something")
   { 

   }
private:
  std::string _temp;
};
```

Comment: With both constructors `Foo(10)` would become ambiguous - either drop the first constructor or the default argument.

Comment: @DanielFrey sorry, I agree, it will result in ambiguity if the second constructor's parameter has default value. So careless. Updated. thanks for pointing that out.